# MongoDB query for Sensors Data Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have Current measuring Sensor and wants to send sensors data Based on **room_no** in MongoDB.

I have Room 1 Schema in Nodejs for MongoDB

```
var Sensor_Schema = mongoose.Schema            //sensor_data schema

({
    room_no: [{type:String, "default":''}],
    current:[{type:String, "default":''}],
    power: [{type:String,  "default":''}], 
}, 

{
    versionKey: false
});
```

I need help in MongoDB query for sending data based on room_no.
I know i have to use aggregation but unable to understand how can i use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the sample that looks like for storing sensors data. I hope this will help you

```
aggregate([{$group :{_id: "$room_no", pwrarr: {$push: "$power"} , crntarr : {$push:'$current'}}}])
```

PS:here pwrarr and crntarr are arrys